# How not to mess up desktop shortcuts on your teachers laptop

Tags: windows-7, windows, resolution, desktop

My teacher asked me to do a presentation. There's a laptop hooked up to a video projector. It's always in duplicate displays mode. My presentation had some comments that only I should see, so I switched to "extend display" mode. And because the resolution is different on the laptop and the projector, all desktoo shortcuts got messed up. My teacher got angry at me. Is there a way to switch without messing up shortcuts?

Comment: You could always take a screen shot before, make the screen changes, once finished change the resolution back the settings before, look over the screen shot to move the desktop icons back in place. I always get a kick out of people that have too many files, etc. on their desktop so if the teacher is storing many PDF files on the desktop and many JPG files, it seems like a good time to explain that they can easily create a folder on the desktop named PDF for all PDF files, etc.

Comment: You can also prevent the ability to move shortcuts but sadly any software that would prevent this, would have a problem, when you introduced the resolution issue that happened.  Teacher needs to understand, this will happen, when Windows gets confused or drivers crash and recover or reinstalled.  It’s basically known this can happen.

Answer (score 2):

There are third-party utilities that record the position of shortcuts and allow these to be restored. Windows is supposed to do something similar by itself as well, but this has reliability issues.

However, the better way is to get used to adapting your own work to the system you are working on. If you will be using the teacher's computer, put your notes on a sheet of paper (Powerpoint allows you to print slide sheets with the notes included).

Like you, I put notes in my presentations and prefer to use extend mode for these, but most people I work with don't, and so I either bring my own computer for presentations, or I keep my notes elsewhere.